# Twitter API - Get id's of all users that interact with a tweet

Tags: twitter

Is there a way in the Twitter API v1.1 to get the id's of all the users that replied, favorited and retweeted to a particular tweet using its id? 
I've searched in older posts but I didn't find an simple way to do it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to `Twitter Staff`  [Episod](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-can-i-get-all-retweets-of-a-specific-tweet/11602),

> It's not possible with the API after the fact for a tweet that has more than 100 retweets. You would need to collect them in real time as they happen to collect them all. The Streaming API is the best bet for tracking such things.

So, you can only get 100 Retweets ID of a tweet through REST API. Move to Streaming API to get all the Retweets ID but you can't get the past data. You can only get data in Streaming API from present - to - future.